# Is there a way to just print the 'y' when your answer is (x, y)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

Is there a way that i can modify this, so my answer only comes out as the 'y' coordinate?? The output I'm looking for is for example 'Triangle Number: 55385'. I'm pretty new to coding, so I don't really understand how to do that. (Python 2.7)

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
t = Symbol('t')
e = Symbol('e')
x = Symbol('x')

print "Triangle Number:", solve(t * (t + 1) / 2 - a, t)
print "Pentagonal Number:", solve((e * (3 * (e) - 1) / 2) - a, e)
print "Hexagonal Number:", solve((x * (2 * (x) - 1)) - a, x)
```

#OUTPUT:

```
    Triangle Number: [-55386, 55385]
    Pentagonal Number: [-95930/3, 31977]
    Hexagonal Number: [-55385/2, 27693]
```

Comment: You're returning a `list` from `solve` so to index the 2nd element you do `solve(.....)[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can request the last entry in the list returned to be printed, instead of the entire sequence:

```
print "Triangle Number:", solve(t * (t + 1) / 2 - a, t)[-1]
print "Pentagonal Number:", solve((e * (3 * (e) - 1) / 2) - a, e)[-1]
print "Hexagonal Number:", solve((x * (2 * (x) - 1)) - a, x)[-1]

#OUTPUT IS BELOW
Triangle Number: 55385
Pentagonal Number: 31977
Hexagonal Number: 27693
```

Comment: Thanks that was perfect!

Comment: You can [accept and upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you bhansa - yes, if the answer helped you, it is always a good idea to accept it as an answer; upvote is nice too! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Something you can do to have solve only return the values that fit your criteria for e, x and t is to define them as nonnegative values. Doing this, solve should only return a list with the values for which you may be looking:

```
>>> e, x, t = symbols('e x t', nonnegative=True, integer=True)
>>> a = 1533776805
>>> solve(t * (t + 1) / 2 - a, t)
[55385]
```